# Missing Data while Reading from Salesforce using Python

Tags: python, salesforce

I am trying to bulk read data from Salesforce using Python. This is creating an output JSON file. However, the file doesn't seem to contain all the data. It has some but not everything.

I confirmed the record id exists in Salesforce but not in JSON file. If I change the WHERE condition to be close around the missing id's modifieddate, it shows up in JSON file. I think there is some kind of size limit on response here but can't find anything.

Has anyone come across such kind of issue? TIA.

**MissingSFData.py**

```
...
sf_object = 'Account'
sf_conn = SalesforceOauthHook(self.sf_conn_id_client, self.sf_conn_id_user).sign_in()

bulk_query = 'select Id,IsDeleted from Account WHERE ModifiedDate >= 2021-06-17T23:10:00+00:00 AND ModifiedDate < 2021-06-21T23:15:00+00:00'
query_results = sf_conn.bulk.__getattr__(sf_object).query(bulk_query) /*bulk.py slightly different from default*/
...
```

**SalesforceOauthHook.py**

```
from simple_salesforce.api import Salesforce /**api.py slightly different from default**/
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook

class SalesforceOauthHook(BaseHook):
...
def sign_in(self):
...
    url = "https://{}.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token".format(instance)
    payload = "&".join([
        "client_id={}".format(client_id),
        "client_secret={}".format(client_secret),
        "grant_type=password&",
        "username={}".format(username),
        "password={}".format(password)
      ])
    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
       }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    credentials = response.json()

    sf = Salesforce(instance_url=credentials["instance_url"],
                    session_id=credentials["access_token"],
                    version="47.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue is with bulk.py in simple_salesforce. It's only reading first batch. Here is the solution to read multiple batches.
https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce/issues/280